# how to use the variable as the name of an object?

Tags: c#

it might be very simple or been asked before, so forgive me for asking it again. im trying to learn :)

if I had a string type variable in C# which would take any of the following values:
"Admin"
"Editor"
"Viewer"
and i also had 3 userforms with the same names as above, is there any way to simply use the variables value to call out a userform instead of going through a switch or if/else statement?
like, can you have something like:
userform(x).show?
x being the variable

would appreciate it alot!

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, Form>`

Comment: @CaiusJard ok i tried:
Dictionary<string, Form> dicForms = new Dictionary<string, Form>();
dicForms.Add("Admin", Admin);
but it says 'Admin' is a type, which is not valid in the given context. am i doing it wrong?

Comment: @P.MAJ Forms are just classes, and like any class you need a reference to a specific instance.

Comment: `dicForms.Add("Admin", new AdminForm())`

Comment: I didn't answer this because I couldn't really think how it would actually be useful; it seems like an XY problem. Why do you have a string that you need to turn into a form?

Comment: @CaiusJard oh im trying to learn C# and am trying to create my first Windows Form Application. so i have a login windows form now done, which connects to MSSQL, and based on the type of the user it brings up the appropriate form. so admin will have a userform in which he/she can grant or remove accesses etc.. i was wondering if there were like 20 usertypes, then would i write a switch statement or rather do it easier.

Comment: Hmm.. yes, I think id just switch it; can't see the need to create 20 forms and store them all in a dict just on the hopes that one of them would be shown.. You could have a `Dictionary<string,Action>` and fill it with delegates that open forms.. but that just feels like complexity for complexity's sake

Comment: @CaiusJard understood :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For "types", you should use Enums.

```
public enum UserType
{
    Admin,
    Editor,
    Viewer,
}
```

2. If you have types that need string representations, you can let C# do it automatically for you, or write your own:

```
UserType userType = UserType.Admin;
string s = userType.ToString(); // "Admin"
string s2 = UserType.Admin.ToString(); // "Admin" as well

public static string GetType(UserType type) => type switch 
{
   UserType.Admin => "Boss",
   UserType.Editor => "Fact Checker",
   UserType.Viewer => "Reader Bee",
   _ => "",
};
```

For getting a form of that type, a `Dictionary<UserType, Form>` would be good:

```
Dictionary<UserType, Form> myForms = new(); // C#9 shorthand - "target typed new expression"
myForms.Add(UserType.Editor, editorForm);
myForms.Add(UserType.Admin, adminForm);
myForms.Add(UserType.Viewer, viewerForm);

editorForm.Text = UserType.Editor.ToString(); // use the built in string or...
editorForm.Text = GetType(UserType.Editor); // ... as defined above
```

If you want to show a specific form, then you can do:

```
UserType typeOfFormToShow = // ... 
myForms[typeOfFormToShow].Show(); // Ensure this form exists in your dictionary, though.
```